# Removing Product Title from Woocommerce Single Product Review Titles

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I'm trying to use PHP in my function.php file to strip out the product title from being injected into the Woocommerce Reviews Title on a product page before/after a product receives a review.

Currently, the default Woocommerce Reviews Title looks like this:

- (Before any reviews): Be the first to review [Product Title]
- (After any review): 1 review for [Product Title]

How can I remove the product title from being used in either instance and simply change the Product Review Titles to a static "Create A Review" regardless of if there are reviews or no reviews?

I believe this is all occurring in the single-products-reviews.php. Unfortunately, I am not versed in PHP well enough to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

You need to copy single-product-reviews.php from wp-contents/plugins/woocommerce/templates/ and to wp-content/themes/youractivetheme/woocommerce/single-product-reviews.php if your theme have no woocommerce folder create one and paste that file into that. This will not override the changes on next update.

Be careful, if you're using some pro theme or non custom developed theme then use child-theme (Here you can learn more about child theme https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/) and then follow the directory structure of yourchildtheme/woocommerce/single-product.reviews.php file.

Once you copy there you need to edit that file. Goto somewhere line no 34 and replace following code

```
$reviews_title = sprintf( esc_html( _n( '%1$s review for %2$s', '%1$s reviews for %2$s', $count, 'woocommerce' ) ), esc_html( $count ), '<span>' . get_the_title() . '</span>' );
```

with

```
$reviews_title = esc_html( 'Create a review', 'woocommerce' );
```

or you can use *woocommerce_reviews_title* filter in your active theme's functions.php file.

```
add_filter("woocommerce_reviews_title", function( $reviews_title, $count, $product )
{
    return $reviews_title = esc_html( 'Create a review', 'woocommerce' );

});
```

Now to change *Be the first to review [product title]* change following code [line #75]

```
'title_reply'         => have_comments() ? esc_html__( 'Add a review', 'woocommerce' ) : sprintf( esc_html__( 'Be the first to review &ldquo;%s&rdquo;', 'woocommerce' ), get_the_title() ),
```

with

```
'title_reply'         => have_comments() ? esc_html__( 'Create a review', 'woocommerce' ) : esc_html__( 'Create a review', 'woocommerce' ),
```

This should be working for you.